# How to delete from two tables same field name in single query?

Tags: ms-access

Help me,

I want to delete same filed name from two tables in single query, I Attached query but it's not working...

```
DELETE PersonalTrainerMasterData ,PersonalTrainerCheckboxData
  FROM PersonalTrainerMasterData INNER JOIN PersonalTrainerCheckboxData
 WHERE PersonalTrainerMasterData.ButtonName = PersonalTrainerCheckboxData.ButtonName
   and PersonalTrainerMasterData.ButtonName='" + deleteButtonForm.getButtonToBeDeleted()
                                               + "'and TabID=1";
```

Comment: I am Using MS ACCESS...

Comment: Are you trying to delete *rows* from these tables? Or are you trying to clear *fields* for certain rows in those tables?

Answer (score 1):

A DELETE only affects one table at a time and removes all rows that are defined in the `criteria`.  Notice the syntax description:

```
DELETE [table.*] FROM table WHERE criteria
```

You should be able to wrap two `DELETE` statements in a transaction. Because `PersonalTrainerMasterData` contains the criteria, `DELETE` it last. E.g.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   DELETE * FROM PersonalTrainerCheckboxData WHERE ...
   DELETE * FROM PersonalTrainerMasterData WHERE ...
COMMIT
```

If needed you could also insert logic to decide whether the `DELETE` should be allowed to `COMMIT` or if it should `ROLLBACK`.